# C# - EDM/EF - Selected tables only or whole database? Best practices

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, edmx

I am still puzzled by a very basic question to which I could not yet find an answer:

If you create in C# an EDM (using database first approach) - are there any best practices in the number of tables you choose?
Would you generally select the whole DB/all tables - to be as flexible as possible later? I.e. you'd work off just one "complete model" in your application.

Or would you try to restrict/limit yourself really to only the tables you absolutely need in your model?

Or generate multiple models with different tables?

Are there any (serious) performance worries, if you have tables in the model, which you are later not actively addressing?

Thank you for any input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your specific situation, consider your problem, whether you need all data or not?? are you working in a Web environment or using local application? if you connect on web it is better to grab data once, but if your tables are too heavy and you do not need all of them, why should you do that?? you load something you need,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! I surely only want to load what I need. But so far I assumed (especially with lazy-loading) , data will only get queried from the DB through the model as needed in that moment. If I create an instance of an EDM, which contains e.g. 100 tables, that does not mean that all 100 tables are loaded into memory. Right? Only once I start querying (LINQ), will data get actually fetched from the DB and the addressed tables. So I believe it would not make a difference of how many tables are in your model initially. Or is this thinking wrong?

Comment: absolutely right, if all table would be fetched, who is going to use Entity framework actually? no body!! As it obvious by the name, EDM is just a model NOT data! So Whenever you load data, no matter lazy or eager loading, it will read your requested data. But depends on eager or lazy, your linq query, it can be different how many data to be reed. just for the start do not worry about the table, it is safe buddy. you can check the answer if it is helpful

Comment: Thank you again for your feedback and that did clear it up further for me!